# How to call an overloaded method from generic type

Tags: c#

I have defined a generic interface

```
interface IHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand:Command
{
     void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

And the class

```
public class MyHandler:
    IHandler<CommandA>,
    IHandler<CommandB>,
    IHandler<CommandC>
{
    public void Handle(CommandA command)
    {...}

    public void Handle(CommandB command)
    {...}

    public void Handle(CommandC command)
    {...}
}
```

For some reasons, I need to call the handler dynamically, and the things I have is the IoC container, a handler's qualified name and the parameter instance (e.g. CommandB). **And my question is how can I invoke the Handle method?**

```
public void DynamicCallHandleMethod(string typeName, Command command)
{
     Container container = new Container();
     container.Register<MyHandler>();

     object handler = container.Resolve(Type.GetType(typeName));
     //handler.Handle(command);  <---- How to make it?
}
```

*Note, I know Reflection may be one of the solutions, so I hope there's another more elegant way, Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Your class does not handle `Command`, it only handles `CommandA`, `CommandB` and `CommandC`. What if you passed a `CommandD` in?

Comment: Your code wouldn't even compile, what exactly is `MyHandler`? Is it supposed to be implementing 3 different interfaces?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, you're right. If the CommandD is passed in, I think it's better if the handler.Handle() method can throw an exception or just do nothing.

Comment: @DavidG sorry for the typo, I just corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 'dynamic' variable and assign it with 'command', then pass this to the handle method.  This should resolve the type at runtime and select the appropriate method.

```
dynamic cmd = command;
handler.Handle( cmd );
```

Alternatively, look into implementing the visitor pattern.

Comment: Be cautious with this approach; it will only work with `public` methods. `internal` methods will blow up.

Comment: @Moho If you're not vouching for it, why suggest it?

Comment: It solves the described problem.  Feel free to offer your own solution, such as a visitor pattern implementation.

Comment: So why define  an interface with a type if you are going to make an object that handles all? To me, this is a code smell. You should be implementing different objects for each command type (the whole point behind injection and generic interface definition) that will most likely have a shared base class. Otherwise, just remove the type from the interface and do type checking inside the method itself.

Comment: I agree, @Juan.

Comment: @Juan I know your concerns. And normally, just as your said,  I create one class just for one command. However, at some point, I have to group related commands in the same class just for high cohesion.

Comment: @Charlie: Why? It goes against OOP. What kind of high cohesion can you get that you don't get with separate classes?

Comment: @Juan I think it's similar to the relationship in MVC that between controller and action. Each action is just like the handler, so I still need the controller to gather all the related actions together just for one domain. However, there's a situation that some third parties may only care about one command(action). Hope it explains.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a Method handling a `Command` value that calls the respective (they might even be private then) methods:

```
public void Handle(Command command)
{
    if(command is CommandA comA)
        Handle(comA);
    else if(command is CommandB comB)
        Handle(comB);
    else if(command is CommandC comC)
        Handle(comC);
    else
        // Handle if necessary.
}
```

also casting the handler as an object on resolve will not expose the Interface. Either you need `var` or implicilty `IHandler` as type.

Comment: The problem with this method, is that when you add `CommandD`, you need to know to add the additional case here or it won't be handled.

Comment: You will hardly avoid that if you want to implement different command types and can't generalize the execution. A different approach entirely might be necessary though. I agree with you that this problem does look a little bit awkward.

Comment: Oh, also this relies on having C#7, worth mentioning :)

Comment: C#7 concatenates it a little bit... otherwise you have to use `Handle((CommandA)command)`.

Comment: It's straightforward, however, If I have two or more implementations, e.g. MyHandler1, MyHandler2,  I may need to repeat similar code again and again. Any thoughts on that?